# Error (10327): VHDL error at Motor_Ctrl.vhd(18): can't determine definition of operator ""<="" -- found 0 possible definitions

Tags: vhdl, quartus

cant understand this.. tried different types for the buffers and nothing works the title says it.

im trying to make a dc motor control and the buffer variabls cant work with the "<=" operator for some reason

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity PWM_Ctrl is
port(PWM_1KHz: in std_logic;
        Ma0: in bit;
        Ma1: in bit;
        Mb0: in bit;
        Mb1: in bit;
        LwheelF: buffer bit;
        LwheelB: buffer bit;
        RwheelF: buffer bit;
        RwheelB: buffer bit);
end;
architecture behave of PWM_Ctrl is 
begin 
process(PWM_1KHz,LwheelF,LwheelB)-- left wheel
begin
if Ma0 = '0' and Ma1 = '0' then LwheelF <= '0' and LwheelB <= '0'; end if; -- No movement
if Ma0 = '0' and Ma1 = '1' then LwheelF <= '1' and LwheelB <= '0'; end if; -- Forward
if Ma0 = '1' and Ma1 = '0' then LwheelF <= '0' and LwheelB <= '1'; end if; -- backward
if Ma0 = '1' and Ma1 = '1' then LwheelF <= '0' and LwheelB <= '0'; end if; -- No movement
end process; 

process(PWM_1KHz,RwheelF,LwheelB) -- right wheel
begin
if Mb0 = '0' and Mb1 = '0' then RwheelF <= '0' and RwheelB <= '0'; end if; -- No movement
if Mb0 = '0' and Mb1 = '1' then RwheelF <= '1' and RwheelB <= '0'; end if; -- Forward
if Mb0 = '1' and Mb1 = '0' then RwheelF <= '0' and RwheelB <= '1'; end if; -- backward
if Mb0 = '1' and Mb1 = '1' then RwheelF <= '0' and RwheelB <= '0'; end if; -- No movement
end process; 

end behave;
```

Comment: This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted via review 4 hours ago by Blastfurnace, PeterJ, CertainPerformance, Tibic4.
So if i want to use the assignment operator and the and as in "&&" on those variabls what do i do? because i need it to only happen when those statements are true:

LwheelF <= '0' and LwheelB <= '0';

Comment: It's not clear from *and as in "&&"* what you're trying to do. VHDL doesn't have expression-statements, an assignment statement assigns values to constants, variables and signals and is delimited by an ending semicolon. Assignment is not an operator and you can't overlay programming language concepts on what is a hardware description language that has a formal syntax and specified semantics. The syntax is rigid enough to identify a syntactic production within two lexical elements. Sequential statements describe algorithms and expressions calculations of values.

Answer (score 0):

`"<="` is the both assignment operator, and also the "less than or equals" operator. Your statement:

`LwheelF <= '0' and LwheelB <= '0';`

And similar all use it in "less than or equals" context. And they cannot be used here because there is no assignment.

I think you meant:

```vhdl
 LwheelF <= '0';
 LwheelB <= '0';
```

etc

Comment: <= is not an assignment operator it is a compound delimiter in an assignment statement syntactic production as well as used as the relational operator. Only the rightmost <= is seen as a relational operator. After the reserved word **then** in the if statement a sequential statement is expected. Here a simple assignment statement whose waveform expression contains a relational operator that can't be defined through the context of overload resolution. The **and** reserved word is seen as a logical operator. The fix shown here using separate assignment statements is valid.